# Send push notifications when local DB is modified

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-messaging

I need to work with android push notifications. I have an app that works with a local database. When this DB is modified i want to send a notification to many concrete person.

I was looking at GCM and Firebase. But i dont know if those ways permit me to do this.

I dont understand good the firebase documentation. If my server side is develope in android and my client side is also in android. I only need to register in FCM service the client side project and then i use the API key that FCM provides me, in the server side with de userID to send notifications?

Comment: Recommending off-site resources is off topic on Stack Overflow. But you could do worse than have a look at the [Firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup) or [this blog post](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2016/08/sending-notifications-between-android.html).

Comment: okk. sorry and thanks